# How do I find the fees and payout info for mining pools?

Tags: mining, mining-pools, fees

I would like to start mining Etherium. But I just realized that it would probably take me years to find anything with my low hashing power. So I would like to join a pool. Most pools only seem to do payouts when you have more than 0.1 Etherium for example. So basically I would mine for a pool for multiple months until I even know if I can trust it or until I even know that my set up and my wallet works or is configured correctly.
So I would like to get a payout sooner. But I also don't want to pay unreasonably high fees.

So I checked on [this website](https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/calculator/eth?HashingPower=18&HashingUnit=MH%2Fs&PowerConsumption=200&CostPerkWh=0) how how much I would mine within 4 days. (around 0.01 ETH)

Then I searched the Internet to find a pool that I'd be comfortable with (payout with ETH >= 0.01 and 1% or less fee), but it is incredibly hard to find the fee and payout info. Either it isn't even mentioned on the pool's homepage (or it's hidden too well?) or it's very unclear/cryptic. E.g. what is that supposed to mean: `Autopayouts from 1.01 ETH (from 0.05) six times a day`? (from [dwarfpool](https://dwarfpool.com/eth)) I don't get it.

So is there an official list of pools and a reliable way to find out what fees they charge and under which circumstances they do a payout?

Am I right that because the blockchain is public, you could look at all the transactions of a pool and thereby calculate this data or at least make educated guesses?

**My system**

- Hashing power: around 18MH/s
- Power cost: None. (I pay a flat price for my power so I could probably even get to 20MH/s by overclocking..)
- OS: Linux (Ubuntu 16.04)
- GPU: GTX 970

Comment: I am also interested in this, if you find a good pool, please let me know which is it , or post it as the answer to your question. Thanks!